# A function does not exit when return passes a function containing promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, discord.js

Ok a little tricky problem popped up for me…
This code runs for every message that a discord bot receives…
First, there's `functionA`, which checks if a message matches a string.
If the string matches, then `functionA` will return `functionB`.
The interesting thing is that when `functionA` returns `functionB` containing a promise (`functionB` contains the promise), things get iffy…

this code exits the function when we return…

```
const discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new discord.Client();

client.on('message', msg => { // msg is "test"
  let app = (function functionA() {
    if(msg.content == "test") { // should be true
      return function functionB() {
        console.log("response") // regular console log
      }
    }
    console.log("should not run") // this does not run, which is good
  })()

  if(typeof app == "function") {
    app();
  }
});

client.login(DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN);
```

this code however does not…

```
const discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new discord.Client();

client.on('message', msg => { // msg is "test"
  let app = (function functionA() {
    if(msg.content == "test") { // should be true
      return function functionB() {
        msg.channel.send("response") // a promise
      }
    }
    console.log("should not run") // this runs for some reason…
  })()

  if(typeof app == "function") {
    app();
  }
});

client.login(DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN);
```

The method `msg.chanel.send("respons")` does return a promise (I'm not actually sure whether that impacts with anything), 
but `functionB` itself should exit `functionA` when we return it

Why doesn't the function stop? Why doesn't `return` exit the function?

Comment: can you put a log inside your if condition....just to verify if its even going there or not?

Comment: I have tried it… the condition is true and the content of the if statement runs

Comment: Sorry, but we need a [mcve]. The code you've shown doesn't behave the way you describe.

Comment: Try `console.log("should not run", msg.content, msg.content === 'test')` for a better overview. Or try breakpoints in debugger to step through each line.

Comment: Thanks to some user on Discord… I realized I'm stupid… the bot sends another message which was not `test` so then the function had to run the `should not run` log

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was an idiot…
the bot sends another message… `response` which then triggers a message event which does not match the if case test… thus sending the `should not run` log that has deprived me of sleep ¬_¬